# Orchard CMS-Tenants site could not see themes in main site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, themes, orchardcms, multi-tenant

I installed a 1.4 Orchard on my local machine. Create a tenant site already.
The problem is i could not see any themes exisintg in main site.

[image: s]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself.
Remove all defaults themes in the tenant's setting config
Before change

```
Themes: TheJournalist;TheThemeMachine
```

After change:

```
Themes:
```

[image]